# Exception web authentication result in windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, facebook, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I want to implement login with Facebook in my windows phone app, when tap on login button appear popup from Facebook, here enter my username and password,  all good, when I want to get token, result

```
WebAuthenticationResult myResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateSilentlyAsync(startUri);
```

I get this exception:

> COMException was unhandled by user code
>
> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a
>   call to a COM component.

Any solution to solve that problem?

Comment: Let me see me your complete code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateSilentlyAsync(startUri)` use `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(requestUri, callbackUri)`Next add a Application_ContractActivated event in App.xaml. You can do this by opening App.xaml and adding ContractActivated like this

`<shell:PhoneApplicationService ContractActivated="Application_ContractActivated" />`

This should add Application_ContractActivated method in App.xaml.cs. In this method you can get the result like this:

```
public WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs WABContinuationArgs { get; set; }

        private void Application_ContractActivated(object sender, IActivatedEventArgs e)
                {
                    var _WABContinuationArgs = e as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs;

                    if (_WABContinuationArgs != null)
                    {
                        WABContinuationArgs = _WABContinuationArgs;
                        var result = WABContinuationArgs.WebAuthenticationResult;
                    }
                }
```

**Note** that this solution is for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and not for Windows Phone 8.1. For Windows Phone 8.1 it's the same principle but you use OnActivated method instead of Application_ContractActivated.